# How to get List from Json Object using Retrofit2 in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I was trying to get list of students from the following json using Retrofit2

```
{
   "students":[
      {
         "address":{
            "city":"DETROIT",
            "state":"MI",
            "street":"4904  Yorkshire Circle",
            "zip":"48228"
         },
         "school":"A B C D School",
         "name":"Mani Nezhad"
      },
      {
         "address":{
            "city":"RED HOOK",
            "state":"NY",
            "street":"1641  Custer Street",
            "zip":"12571"
         },
         "school":"X Y Z School",
         "name":"Jane Lindberg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my Model Class

```
data class Student(
    val name: String,
    val school: String,
    val address: Address
) {
    data class Address(val street: String, val city: String, val state: String, val zip: String)
```

And here is the method written in Interface:

```
    @GET("abcd")
    fun getStudents(@Query("token") token: String): Call<List<Student>>
```

but whenever I run the app I get this error

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I understand that I was trying to getch array from a json which starts with `{` curly bracket.
Now my question is how can I fetch this student array from this type of json which starts with the curly bracket?

Comment: you have to create a a new class (for example: StudentsList) with object of List<Student> and then instead of Call<List<Student>> use Call<StudentsList>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response is object not Array . So you should create Wrapper Object which will hold the `List<Student>` . Something like this .

```
    data class ApiResponse(val students: List<Student>)


@GET("abcd")
fun getStudents(@Query("token") token: String): Call<ApiResponse>
```